# Can I use a manually created index and query nodes using Cypher?

Tags: java, neo4j

Here I have created a manual/legacy index and added some nodes with certain properties into it.

```
IndexManager indexy = graphdb.index();
Index<Node>indexery = indexy.forNodes("Main_Twitter_Index");
indexery.add(one,"Name",one.getProperty("Name"));
indexery.add(one,"Email",one.getProperty("Email"));
indexery.add(four,"Name",four.getProperty("Name"));
indexery.add(four,"Email",four.getProperty("Email"));
```

Now, to query the nodes of that index neo4j suggests [query](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-search.html#indexing-search-query), which uses a key-value pair binding. My question is can I query the same nodes added into the manual index using a simple cypher query like,

```
START n=node:Main_Twitter_Index(Name = 'Akina')
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Neo4j are you using? The method you describe is the typical index search for anything before 2.0, before they added schema indexing. Your query should work, even in 2.0. Are you having problems running it?

Comment: Version 1.8. Not sure about problems as I haven't checked it since I don't have access to db as of now. I wanted to know if it is possible in concept.

Comment: I'm using that pattern all the time with 1.8.2, so it should work for you. If you want, you can also do composite key lookups also, using more than 1 key, you have access to most of the lucene query language, the only thing you can't do is a numeric lookup.